# MySQL Random Order and Save in the Database without ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to rearrange my table. Please note that this table has around 250k rows.

Id is a auto increment field.

**Current Table (Article)**

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | details | category |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | detail1 | cat1     |
|  2 | detail2 | cat2     |
|  3 | detail3 | cat3     |
+----+---------+----------+
```

**Need to Change Like this**

```
| id | details | category |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | detail3 | cat3     |
|  2 | detail1 | cat1     |
|  3 | detail2 | cat2     |
+----+---------+----------+
```

In words basically I need to re-order (Randomly) rows and **saved in the table**. Reorder should be only without ID. I mean all aim of this process is change(actually changing id with another id) the ID of articles.

Can we do this with just only MySQL? (I asked it here because I can do this using PHP, I mean create temporary table and them empty this and then inserting again randomly. But I would like to know that is there way to do with just MySQL query or two)

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the `id` using `update`:

```
set @id := 0
update t
    set id = (@id := @id + 1)
    order by rand();
```